# Architecture of crypto exchange webiste

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am working on a project and I am unable to figure out the architecture of a crypto exchange wallet in which I want to convert fiat currency to my own cryptocurrency which has same value

i.e, 1 INR = 1 cyr {cryptorupee}

I want to make the above conversion happen.

Comment: Do you need only one way conversion, fiat -> crypto, or both ways?

Comment: from fiat to crypto one specific and for crypto to fiat other one so that a particular party during a trade can use it.